# How build Team App using SharePoint SPFX webpart

Tags: microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

I have a SPFX web part, working perfectly fine in SharePoint online sites. In App catalog site its syncing with Team successfully.

I add it in SharePoint page and add pages url in a Teams tab. It worked fine over there as well.

But problem occurs when I am trying to build a Teams App via App Studio, add this Page URL in Tab configuration. But it is not even open the SharePoint page in it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. (FYK: I have no coding background)

Comment: Hi @cjs, Could you please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tabs-in-sharepoint#more-information) document, it explains how to add tabs in sharepoint.

Comment: Hi @Jagadeesh-MSFT.  I want to add a SPFX webpart into a Teams App.  the link you have shared is other way around.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement your Microsoft Teams tabs using SharePoint Framework. Using SharePoint Framework significantly simplifies Teams tab development process as Teams tabs can be automatically hosted within SharePoint without any need for external services. you can use [tab with spfx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab) for your work around.